# How to update the value of a Label in footer template of a gridview?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that has editable fields in it am calculating the sum of every column and displaying it in the footer columns my gridview column looks like 
This is not updating the value can anyone please help me where i should correct my code?

```
if (i == objGrid.rows.length)
{   
   objGrid.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].innerText = ClsSum;
   objGrid.rows[i].cells[3].children[0].innerText = NonSaleSum;
   objGrid.rows[i].cells[7].children[0].innerText = SecSum;
}
```

Comment: try if (i == (objGrid.rows.length-1))

Comment: Is it not updating only on footer or ?

Comment: Could you post bit more details ?Post your code on what event it's not updating your footer label?

Comment: On which event you are executing this code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this also, put below code out side of loop

//create css class called "footerClass" and apply on column fotter template

```
var objGrid= document.getElementById('<%=YourGrid.ClientID%>');
var cells = objGrid.getElementsByClassName('footerClass') 

cells[0].innerText = ClsSum;
cells[1].innerText = NonSaleSum;
cells[2].innerText = SecSum;
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the answer but its coming up as NaN

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the rows.length -1. 
And make sure that the code snippet will get executed after the postback.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code executes after you bind your gridview . So please check if you have applied 
 `(!IsPostBack)` in your GridviewBind method .
Also check does  if your code reaches this method when reloads or updates your values ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are  using `Grid_RowDataBound()` event and accordingly that you can try this

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   { 
         e.Row.cells[2].children[0].innerText = ClsSum;
         e.Row.cells[3].children[0].innerText = NonSaleSum;
         e.Row.cells[7].children[0].innerText = SecSum;
    }
}
```